# Injecting the current user using Autofac and ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, autofac

I'm trying out Autofac and the architecture described in [this](http://techbrij.com/service-layer-entity-framework-asp-net-mvc-unit-testing) article. 
With Ninject I used to be able to use the following to retireve the current user using Ninject:

```
kernel.Bind<ApplicationUser>().ToMethod(c => (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()).FindById(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId<int>()));
```

Using the above, one could then easily get access to the currently logged in user in both your controllers and repositories e.g:

```
private readonly ApplicationUser _user;
public ProductsController(ApplicationUser user)
{
    _user = user;
}

private readonly ApplicationUser _user;
public SectorRepository(ApplicationUser user)
{
    _user = user;
}
```

I've experimented with Autofac and so far could not achieve the same results

How would I be able to accomplish the same or similar using Autofac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
       builder.Register(
                c => (HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>())
                    .FindById(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId())).As<ApplicationUser>();
}
```